# Flutter generalized parameter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that uses a database what is generated by Moor.

Normally I would need 3 pages but since all 3 pages would look the same, the code would be the same. Only difference is the DAO they use.

So I have `FirstDao`, `SecondDao`, `ThirdDao`. All of them have the `list()` method and all of them return different type of objects (`FirstType`, `SecondType`, `ThirdType`) At the moment this is how I made it work but I am not sure is this a good way:

```
class RollingListChoice<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  T dao;

  RollingListChoice(this.dao);

  @override
  _RollingListChoiceState createState() =>
      _RollingListChoiceState(dao);
 }

class _RollingListChoiceState<T> extends State<RollingListChoice> {
  T dao;

  _RollingListChoiceState(this.dao);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(getDao().list());
  }


  getDao() {
    if (dao.runtimeType == FirstDao) {
      FirstDao mydao = dao as FirstDao;
      return mydao;
    } else if (dao.runtimeType == SecondDao) {
      SecondDaomydao = dao as SecondDao;
      return mydao;
    } else if (dao.runtimeType == ThirdDao) {
      ThirdDao mydao = dao as ThirdDao;
      return mydao;
    }
  }

}
```

Any way to improve the code? Is there any best practice for this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can have an interface for `DAO` classes (for example `IDAO`) and replace `RollingListChoice<T>` with `RollingListChoice<T extends IDAO>` to restrict type `T` to specific classes. by that, you don't need to cast `dao` in `getDao()` method and you will be sure that `dao` has `list()` method.

```dart
abstract class IDAO {
  String list();
}

class RollingListChoice<T extends IDAO> extends StatefulWidget {
  T dao;

  RollingListChoice(this.dao);

  @override
  _RollingListChoiceState createState() =>
      _RollingListChoiceState(dao);
 }

class _RollingListChoiceState<T extends IDAO> extends State<RollingListChoice> {
  T dao;

  _RollingListChoiceState(this.dao);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text(dao.list());
}
```

if you do mentioned changes you don't need to `getDao()` method, but you can change `getDao()` method like this as well:

```dart
getDao() {
  if (dao is FirstDao) {
    FirstDao mydao = dao as FirstDao;
    return mydao;
  } else if (dao is SecondDao) {
    SecondDaomydao = dao as SecondDao;
    return mydao;
  } else if (dao is ThirdDao) {
    ThirdDao mydao = dao as ThirdDao;
    return mydao;
  }
}
```

Comment: My DAOs classes are looking like this: `class FirstDao extends DatabaseAccessor<AppDatabase>
    with _$FirstDaoMixin {}` - I don't think your way could work for me but thanks for the response.

Comment: @stacktrace2234 NP. :)

Comment: I think a small tweak of @Hamed answer would do. `class FirstDao extends DatabaseAccessor<AppDatabase>     with _$FirstDaoMixin implements IDAO{}`